# Make a rectangle move to point B one pixel at a time in a strait line

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a rectangle which when I hold down the mouse button I want that rectangle to move to that point following a strait line 1 pixel at a time.

This is my code so far (I put comments in it so you can understand)

```
    float distanceX = finalX - x; //the number of pixels needed to get to destination on the X axis
    float distanceY = finalY - y; // same as above but Y axis
    float moveX = distanceX > 0 ? 1 : -1; // I only want it to move 1 pixel per render
    float moveY = distanceY > 0 ? 1 : -1; // same as above

    Array<Stuff> collidedX = new Array<Stuff>(); //saves collisions seperately for x and y
    Array<Stuff> collidedY = new Array<Stuff>(); //because I want the square to move where the mouse is pointing even if it means only aligning one axis

    for (Stuff s : collidables) {
        if (overlapsT(s, x + moveX, y)) {
            collidedX.add(s);
        }
    }
    if (collidedX.size < 1) {
        if (distanceX != 0)
            x += moveX;
    }
    for (Stuff s : collidables) {
        if (overlapsT(s, x, y + moveY)) {
            collidedY.add(s);
        }
    }
    if (collidedY.size < 1) {
        if (distanceY != 0)
            y += moveY;
    }
```

right now the problem is it goes perfectly diagonal until it lines up with one of the axis and then moves up down left or right to the destination.

I don't want to move fractions of pixels. The way my custom physics engine works is each pixel matters, fractional pixels are no good so I am trying to figure out how to smooth the path or rather how to decide when to add 1 to x and then y.

Comment: Separate your game logic and keep it independent from device specific units like pixels (what if it is run on another device with twice, ten or hundred times as much pixels as your device, or even no pixels at all?). Also don't over complicate your game logic by using imaginary pixels. If your physics engine forces you to couple game logic with device specific units then consider using a different physics engine. See also: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels/.

Comment: @Xoppa right now I am stretching the screen to fit any resolution using a viewport so the game is consistently 1920x1080 across all devices. Yes it will look perfect on 1080p and smaller on smaller resolutions and bigger on bigger resolutions but I want this game to be multiplayer and I want everyone to see the same exact things on the screen even if it means shrinking things down. If I use inches or something like that how will I make everything fit on the screen the same exact way for everyone? Definitely reading that article though, thanks for the link!

Comment: In that case it aren't pixels you are using, it are meaningless imaginary units. Just specify the size in meaningfull units, e.g. in meters, that you want your viewport to be. It will still look the same on different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I can't comment, so I have to answer. I think the Bresenham's line algorithm will help you out. It's for drawing rasterize lines.

[Bresenham](http://members.chello.at/easyfilter/bresenham.html)